# I am using Phoenix first time why am I getting this error "application is not available"?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

> [info] Running Slicker.Endpoint with Cowboy using
>   http://localhost:4000 You have configured application :Slicker in your
>   configuration file, but the application is not available.
>
> This usually means one of:
>
> 1. You have not added the application as a dependency in a mix.exs file.
> 2. You are configuring an application that does not really exist.
>
> Please ensure :Slicker exists or remove the configuration.

my project exist here -> [Github link](https://github.com/ankit-kumar-dwivedi/slicker)

below is mix.exs file

```
defmodule Slicker.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :slicker,
     version: "0.0.1",
     elixir: "~> 1.2",
     elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
     compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     aliases: aliases(),
     deps: deps()]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application.
  #
  # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information.
  def application do
    [mod: {Slicker, []},
     applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_pubsub, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
                    :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex, :comeonin]]
  end

  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "web", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib", "web"]

  # Specifies your project dependencies.
  #
  # Type `mix help deps` for examples and options.
  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.5"},
     {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
     {:bcrypt_elixir, "~> 1.0"},
     {:comeonin, "~> 4.1"},
     {:guardian, "~> 1.0"},
     {:cors_plug, "~> 1.5"}]
  end

  # Aliases are shortcuts or tasks specific to the current project.
  # For example, to create, migrate and run the seeds file at once:
  #
  #     $ mix ecto.setup
  #
  # See the documentation for `Mix` for more info on aliases.
  defp aliases do
    ["ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
     "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"],
     "test": ["ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate", "test"]]
  end
end
```

Comment: You have two directories here. How do you run your application?

Comment: thanks @mudasobwa that was the issue.

Comment: @denis.peplin I am using React for frontend and phoenix for backend so two different directories